# 「/etc/cron.d/raid-check」と「/etc/cron.d/sysstat」について

Tags: centos, cron

**/etc/cron.d/以下に見慣れないファイルが2つあるのですが、**
・下記はデフォルトで存在するファイルですか？
・削除しない方が良いですか？

・raid-check
・sysstat

---

**環境**
・CentOS7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

無闇に削除する前に、まずは何のファイルなのか調べる癖を付けましょう。

---

CentOSであれば`rpm`コマンドの`-f`オプションで対象のファイルがどのパッケージに属するものかを調べることができます。
(ここで仮に結果が表示されなければ、パッケージの管理外なファイルという事になる)

```
# rpm -qf /etc/cron.d/raid-check
mdadm-4.1-rc1_2.el7.x86_64
# rpm -qf /etc/cron.d/sysstat
sysstat-10.1.5-17.el7.x86_64
```

パッケージ名が表示されたなら、今度は`rpm`コマンドの`-i`オプションでパッケージの説明(概要)を確認します。

```
# rpm -qi mdadm
# rpm -qi sysstat
```

---

- `raid-check (mdadm)`はソフトウェアRAIDを使用している場合にRAIDのチェックを行うタスクです。該当の環境を利用していなければ実行は不要でしょう。
- `sysstat` はシステムのリソース状態を定期的に取得しログファイルに記録しておくタスクです。必要かどうかは実際の使い方で判断してみてください。

cronのタスクなので、不要なら一旦コメントアウトで様子を見るくらいでいいのかなと個人的には思います。

参考:
[CentOS 6 サーバーのリソース状態を sysstat で監視しよう](https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/centos6-sysstat-1/)